# PyAV inconsistency when parsing packets from h264 frames

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, h.264, pyav

When producing H.264 frames and decoding them using pyAV, packets are parsed from frames only when invoking the `parse` methods twice.

**Consider the following test H.264 input, created using:**

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=10:size=1280x720:rate=30 -f image2 -vcodec libx264 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -force_key_frames source -x264-params keyint=1:scenecut=0 "frame-%4d.h264"`

Now, using pyAV to parse the first frame:

```
import av
codec = av.CodecContext.create('h264', 'r')
with open('/path/to/frame-0001.h264', 'rb') as file_handler:
    chunk = file_handler.read()
    packets = codec.parse(chunk) # This line needs to be invoked twice to parse packets
```

packets remain empty unless the last line is invoked again (`packets = codec.parse(chunk)`)

Also, for different real life examples I cannot characterize, it seems that decoding frames from packets also require several decode invocations:

```
packet = packets[0]
frames = codec.decode(packet) # This line needs to be invoked 2-3 times to actually receive frames.
```

Does anyone know anything about this incosistent behavior of pyAV?

*(Using Python 3.8.12 on macOS Monterey 12.3.1, ffmpeg 4.4.1, pyAV 9.0.2)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expected PyAV behavior. Not only, it is an expected behavior of the underlying `libav`. One packet does not guarantee a frame, and multiple packets may be needed before producing a frame. This is apparent in [FFmpeg's video decoder example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c):

```c
    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
```

If it needs more packets to form a frame, it throws the `EAGAIN` error.

[edit]

Actually, the above example is not a good example as it just exits on `EAGAIN`. To retrieve a frame, it should rather `continue` on `EAGAIN`:

```c
    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
        if (AVERROR(EAGAIN))
            continue;
        if (ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
```

[edit]

**pyav's `codec.parse()`**

The decoding sometimes needing additional calls is a fairly well-known fact, but the parser needing to flush is less common. Here is the difference between PyAV and FFmpeg:

PyAV parses the input data with `av_parser_parse2()` like this [[ref]](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/0271719b85b3981accca7e7cfaaa13bb1ae31db9/av/codec/context.pyx#L355):

```py
        while True:

            with nogil:
                consumed = lib.av_parser_parse2(
                    self.parser,
                    self.ptr,
                    &out_data, &out_size,
                    in_data, in_size,
                    lib.AV_NOPTS_VALUE, lib.AV_NOPTS_VALUE,
                    0
                )
            err_check(consumed)

            # ...snip...

            if not in_size:
                # This was a flush. Only one packet should ever be returned.
                break

            in_data += consumed
            in_size -= consumed

            if not in_size:
                # Aaaand now we're done.
                break
```

So it reads until the input data is 100% consumed and note that it does not call `av_parser_parse2` at end of buffer (which makes sense as the input data may be only a part of the stream data.

In contrast, FFmpeg does not call `av_parser_parse2` directly and uses [`parse_packet`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavformat/demux.c#L1118) and you can see how it handles the similar situation:

```c
while (size > 0 || (flush && got_output)) {
   int64_t next_pts = pkt->pts;
   int64_t next_dts = pkt->dts;
   int len;

   len = av_parser_parse2(sti->parser, sti->avctx,
                          &out_pkt->data, &out_pkt->size, data, size,
                          pkt->pts, pkt->dts, pkt->pos);
```

It calls `av_parser_parse2` also to flush the stream after input data stream is exhausted. So, you need to do the same in PyAV: after all your frames are read, call `codec.parse()` one last time to flush the last packet.

Comment: I assume it could be because a frame might span across different packets or because of error correction behavior of a packet in a stream? in that case how does it know to form a frame if I attempt to decode exactly the same packet again? And also why does that apply to the packet parsing as well? (not only the frame decoding)

Comment: It's the former. You need to feed the next packet. If there is an error in packet, it would return a non-`EAGAIN` error.

Comment: The example I provided works when I try to decode the same packet again rather than the next packet (in my case the frame is exactly in the first packet completely).

Comment: On both parser and decoder, what happens if you call again with no input argument (thus flushing the demuxer and decoder)? Do you get the same output?

Comment: Yes you are correct! flushing the buffer seems to do the trick for both packet parsing and frame decoding: https://pyav.org/docs/develop/api/codec.html?highlight=parse#av.codec.context.CodecContext.parse (If you care to elaborate and explain the behavior from the source code I will mark it as the accepted answer)

Comment: Did a bit more digging (well a lot more than originally intended) on parsing.